# Youtube API returns no results

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am having problems loading a playlist of videos from Youtube. I follow [this guide](https://www.pavey.me/2016/04/aspnet-c-retrieving-list-of-videos-from.html) but cant figure out what is wrong because I don't get an error.

```
 var YouTubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = "MyAPIID"}); 
 var ChannelListRequest = YouTubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
 ChannelListRequest.ForUsername = "YoutubeUser";    
 var ListResponse = ChannelListRequest.Execute();

 foreach (var channel in ListResponse.Items) //No content in ListResponse.Items
```

When I execute the request it returns a empty response. The API Id is correct because it becomes error if I use a old one. I have tried with the username and id from the channel but none worked. What am I missing?

Comment: Could it be that your lists are private?

Comment: @NielsdeSchrijver Tried several playlists/channels none worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I tried some things and I managed to retrieve my playlists of my channel like so:

```
var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
     ApiKey = "yourapikey",
     ApplicationName = this.GetType().Name
});

var playListRequest = service.Playlists.List("snippet");
playListRequest.ChannelId = "yourchannelid";
var result = await playListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

With the playlist Id's you get from this response you can retrieve the video's like so:

```
var playListItemsRequest = service.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
playListItemsRequest.PlaylistId = "yourplaylistid";
var result = await playListItemsRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```